# Loop isn't working as expected in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have this example df:

```
test1 <- c(2,3,4,5)
test2 <- c(6,7,8,11)
testing.df<- as.data.frame(rbind(test1,test2))
```

And here is my loop that isn't working as expected:

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
  return (x - mean(x))/ (sd(x)) }
```

When I apply my function `normalize` to my df:

```
testing.df[,3:4] <- as.data.frame(lapply(testing.df[,c(3:4)], normalize))
```

I get this output:

```
#      V1 V2 V3 V4
#test1  2  3 -2 -3
#test2  6  7  2  3
```

I am supposed to get

```
#      V1  V2        V3         V4
#test1  2  3 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#test2  6  7  0.7071068  0.7071067
```

My function is supposed to take the value in a column and subtract the mean of that column. Then, it divides that difference by the standard deviation in that column. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks @AdamO. If you make this as an answer, I will gladly accept. What a silly mistake. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` takes as an argument `(x-mean(x))` and the rest is ignored. Remove the `return` argument altogether for better code. : `normalize <- function(x) {(x - mean(x))/ (sd(x))}`. See `?scale` also.